# Simple way to get dem, grayscale elevation maps for EU (10m resolution)

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I need 10 or 12.5 m spatial resolution dem maps of mountainous areas, precisely grey scale(map with height data) version for use in 3d software.

I found geoTiff maps from Copernicus, but they are 25m spatial and I need more precision.

Other option is https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home, data from Sentinel satellites, but it is a pain, because I need to use Snap software and then another one and still I cant get it to work properly. So hard to get simple gray scale elevation map out of Sentinel 1 satellite data. Lost a lot of time trying to do it.

I seek some resource to get that resolution Geo Tiff preferably or a fast, uncomplicated way to get 10m spatial resolution maps.

Update 1: I do not need one map for whole Europe. Smaller area maps like one for one part of the Alps, another for another part,.. are all right, but they need to be 10m or 12.5m spartial res.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alps, Alps.. What's Alps?

> Alps are the highest and most extensive mountain range system that lies entirely in Europe, stretching approximately 1,200 km (750 mi) across seven Alpine countries (from west to east): France, Switzerland, Italy, Liechtenstein, Austria, Germany, and Slovenia.

Let's check what's available.

- France: https://geoservices.ign.fr/rgealti
- Switzerland: https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/geodata/height/alti3d.html
- Italy: http://tinitaly.pi.ingv.it/
- Liechtenstain: see Switzerland
- Austria: 10 m raster - https://www.data.gv.at/katalog/dataset/d88a1246-9684-480b-a480-ff63286b35b7
- Germany: no detailed open source data for whole country, you can search by federal countries, example for Bayern - https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/produkte/3dprodukte/gelaende.html where you can get 50 and 200 m data, however you can buy 10 m datasets
- Slovenia: http://gis.arso.gov.si/evode/profile.aspx?id=atlas_voda_Lidar@Arso&culture=en-US

Hope it helps,
Grzegorz